# How to add automated data labels to line plot?

Tags: r

I've produced a simple line plot using base R and want to add data labels to the point. Any idea how to do this in an automated way? Picture of graph produced here
[image]

`plot(grant$year, grant$grantee, type = "o", xlab = "Year", ylab = "Number of Grantees", pch = 16,  col = "dark blue", lwd = 3, cex = 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I estimated your data from the linked picture.  By adding `text(grant$year, grant$grantee, labels = grant$grantee, pos = 3)` after your plot gives us labels. `pos = 3` puts the labels above the data points.

```
year <- c(2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020)
grantee <- c(50,55,51,30,52,83)
grant <- data.frame(year, grantee)
plot(grant$year, grant$grantee, type = "o", xlab = "Year", ylab = "Number of Grantees", pch = 16,  col = "dark blue", lwd = 3, cex = 2)
text(grant$year, grant$grantee, labels = grant$grantee, pos = 3)
```